# environment variable included in printenv but can't echo them

Tags: bash, echo, environment

I have a problem that is puzzling me.
I am inside a docker container on a ubuntu machine using a bash shell.
I want to check if the environment variable called "ENVIRONMENT" used by my code is properly set.

When I do "printenv" I can see the variables:

```
root@863cf368a72d:/data-cron# printenv
ENVIRONMENT = staging
PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.5
HOME=/root
```

(etc, can't disclose the full details of the environment variables of this product).

Now, if I do:

```
root@863cf368a72d:/data-cron# echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

I get nothing! But if I try with another variable:

```
root@863cf368a72d:/data-cron# echo $HOME
```

I get the right answer:

```
/root
```

Needless to say, my code doesn't work because the variable "ENVIRONMENT" is set to None

Does anyone have any idea? I am puzzled by the mismatch between printenv and echo, I never saw that happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: I can reproduce this if I start bash like this: `env 'ENVIRONMENT = staging' bash` (but `env ENVIRONMENT=staging' bash` works fine). Are you sure the variable `ENVIRONMENT` is set properly, i.e doesn't have spaces in its name? Because if it has, bash can't expand it.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you posted, you don't have an environment variable named `ENVIRONMENT`, but one named `ENVIRONMENT` , as you can see from the space in front of the equal sign. Environment variables can be any string, so this variable is not valid.

While you can't set an environment variable with such an odd name (containing a space) from the shell, you can do so from most other applications. Try to grep for where you have a such a string in your configuration. I would not be surprised if this is found in your docker configuration.

BTW, if you want to see exactly what's in a similarily named environment variable, you could also do a

```
xxd <(printenv|grep ENVIRONMENT)
```

which should show you byte by byte the name of the variable, including possible unprintable characters.